# error from slick in play scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I play around with scala, play and slick.
I am wondering how I would catch an error from slick in play.

Lets say, there is an DAO:

```
trait UserDao extends DAOSlick with UserComponent with HasDatabaseConfig[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  def getUserWithId(id: UUID) = {
    db.run(userTable.filter { x => x.userId === id }.result.head)
  }
}
```

This trait is used in my Controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller with UserDao {
  import driver.api._

   def getUser(id: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    getUserWithId(UUID.fromString(id)).map {
      res => Ok(Json.toJson(res))
    }
  }
}
```

If there is no user with given ID, slick will raise an error:

```
[NoSuchElementException: Invoker.first]
```

In my client (browser), I get an Status 500 (Internal Server Error).
I don't find examples, how slick and play is supposed to work together with error messages from the database or slick.

Should the return type of all DAOs be an Try[User]? 
In all examples I saw, nobody cares about failing slick calls. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should the return type of all DAOs be an Try[User]? In all examples I saw, nobody cares about failing slick calls. What am I missing?

You are missing [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option). Change your DAO method to return `Option[User]` and instead calling `head` call `headOption` on `result`.

Comment: Ok, that could be an option.
But still, I don't know the exact error. Maybe I want to give different status codes back to my client. 
For example: If I insert an "existing user", I want to let my my client know, if there is a duplicate key error (raised by my db).

Comment: Anyway, this answers my question above. Thanks!

Comment: `Maybe I want to give different status codes back to my client.` Correct, return `notFound` response.